# Training for SharePoint 2019

Tags: training

I was wondering if someone could provide some advice. We have a SharePoint 2010 system we plan to upgrade to SharePoint 2019. I was hoping to enroll in some SharePoint 2019 Administration training but after searching high and low, I note no one is offering specific SharePoint 2019 Admin training. I note also there are not many books available on Amazon covering SharePoint 2019. Is this because there is little difference between SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2019 administration?  And therefore, I would be best advised to attend a SharePoint 2016 admin course? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  This site is going in a bad direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no much difference SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2019. The SharePoint 2019 is more focused on the modern SharePointing as like SharePoint online.. pages are responsive and have improved on the hybrid configuration.

When it comes to migration, the basic thumb rule is same. Meaning, we can't migrate directly from SharePoint 2010 to 2019 in fact that is not recommended, we need to go over the migration ladder, i. e. sharepoint 2010 - > 2013 - > 2016 - >finally to 2019.

Before migration have development, testing, staging and production server set up... however, if your content is less, you can minimize these setup to development and production server.

As your migration would be from SP 2010 version, the main key point or the challenge would be converting the authentication to claim as from SP 2013 version onwards the default authentication is claim. So we need to pay special attention here, however,  no need to be in panic as before migrating to SP 2019, in 2013 and 2016 versions, this will be stabilized.

**Few check lists :**

- In migration project, the planning is the key parameter, so the better you plan, better you will get results... so have proper planning ready up front.
- Have details inventory of your sources SharePoint each objects like webApplication, site, list library, item, version,  etc.
- Identify your key complex applications from your source SharePoint... and if you think this may causes issues, so for them always plan B ready.
- Need to have sophisticated rollback plan in place.

**For more tips and tricks in SharePoint migration project, please refer the below article :**

[SharePoint Migration: Basic tips and tricks in migration project](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/basic-tips-and-tricks-in-sharepoint-migration-project/)